# TypeError: get_member() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Tags: discord.py

sorry for this noob question. I'm trying to make a Discord bot with Python. I want the member Object. I only know the ID from the user. I tried this: `user = discord.Guild.get_member(user_id = the user id)` But I get this error: TypeError: get_member() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'. But I thought that I don't need this argument! In the Documenation they say I don't need that https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.get_member
I tried several Ideas but idk what I should do next.
Here's a more detailed version of my code:

`@client.event async def on_message(message): if message.content == "test": guild = discord.Guild user = guild.guild.get_member(user_id = the id from a user) await message.channel.send(user)`

Comment: Could you attach a more detailed code?

Comment: I did but idk why the formatting is trash :/

Comment: I updated mu solution, try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple example how to get member in guild:

```py
@bot.command()
async def getmember(context):
    member = context.guild.get_member(your_user_id)
```

UPD: Try this solution:

```py
@client.event 
async def on_message(message):     
    if message.content == "test":         
        guild = message.author.guild
        user = guild.get_member(your_user_id)         
        await message.channel.send(user)
```

Comment: I tried it but now It's a "NoneType". For example: If I try to get the name of the user with "name = user.name" I get this error: "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name' "

Comment: Maybe your user_id is wrong and `get_member` return you NoneType object. Try to `print(user)` after `user = guild.get_member(your_user_id)` and check it.